# drag and drop in drupal 6 block

Tags: drupal-6

I am working on drupal. I am facing problem in block. There is no drag and drop function on the page. When i dissable javascript on my browser  it show weight option to set manually, after enable again it is not showing.

can any one suggest about this type of problem. if there is any css related issue please suggest me about this

Answer (score 0):

Usually, when this happens, the `<?php print $scripts; ?>` call in your theme's `page.tpl.php` is missing, so that Drupal's JavaScript files aren't being included (it's JavaScript that creates the drag and drop features). Or there is an error/conflict in your JavaScript/jQuery.

Is `$scripts` being printed in your theme?

Comment: which  javascript is enable for this function?

Comment: I believe it's `/modules/block/block.js`

Comment: $scripted is printed in my theam

Comment: Hard to tell for sure then. Is it possible to share a link to your website? For what it's worth, the class for the table dragging widget is `.tabledrag-handle`, in case that's overriden anywhere.

Comment: @g_thom Actually this wouldn't happen if the `<?php print $scripts; ?>` call was missing, since the drag and drop functionality is done as progressive enhancement, so if $scripts were missing, the select list of weights would remain. What he's describing (the thing disappearing and the plain html select list appearing only when he disables javascript) sounds more like a conflict of jQuery versions, or some other scripts overriding the core functionality